# If input is set to checked with PHP, jQuery should call some functions

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

1) If POST value is set save the content from the POST value in a variable.

```
if(isset($_POST["spart"])) {
    $spart = $_POST["spart"];
 }else{
        $spart = '';
 }
```

2) If variable contains a certain value, make the input field checked.

```
<input id="radio_dump_select_spart1x2" class="copy" type="radio" name="spart" value="1x2" <?php if ($spart=="1x2") echo 'checked="checked"';?>>
```

The problem now is that some jQuery functions should be called if a checkbox is checked. I already have them in the header but they only work if the user clicks on it. It doesn't work if it is set in PHP like described above.

3) OK, let's try to call some actions if input is checked:

```
<input id="radio_dump" type="radio" name="spart" value="1x2" <?php if ($spart=="1x2") echo 'checked="checked"';?> onclick="if($(this).is(':checked')) { alert('test'); hide_them_all(); $('#select_tb').show(); }; return true"> Text</div>
```

I thought I could use the `onclick` attribute, but it seems that it won't work.

Comment: It's not really clear to me from your question what you'd like to do. Maybe you could re-read it and make a list of what should happen in which order?

Comment: I edited my question. Hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it can be done:

```
<?php if ($spart=="1x2") { ?>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
  $( function() {
   alert('test'); 
   hide_them_all(); 
   $('#select_tb').show();
  } );
 </script>
<?php } ?>
```

You can insert this almost anywhere with no problems.

Comment: Don't know why but it doesn't work. It outputs the JS Code but nothing happens.

Comment: If I place it in the `header` section of the HTML document and in the `$(document).ready(function(){` area , than it seems to work.

Comment: well `$( function() {` is just a shorted declaration for `$(document).ready( function() {`, they are exactly the same.  But if you add `<script...>...</script>` into your javascript code, something weird should happen.  Honestly, there should be no problems at all taking the exact code I put in my answer and copying it under the input element on the page.  It is important that you copy the `<script>` tags with it, they are what identify that text as javascript for the browser.

Comment: I found the reason why it didn't worked. You missed a `);` before the last php code ... Otherwise you are right.

Comment: Oppps ><  Thats my bad! :p  Good find!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if($("#radio_dump").is(":checked")) {
         alert("Do something");
    }
});
```

Comment: I already have this but this only works if the user really clicks on the input element. If I set it with PHP it doesn't work.

Comment: So I put in your code. It also works. But now I have duplicate code: One time in between the `click` function and one time without it.